# MIPS Assembly, matrix multiplication

Tags: mips, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to implement matrix multiplication using MIPS assembly. There is an error on the line "lw $t4, 0($t4)" on the second loop through the k_loop. The error is: "Runtime exception at 0x00400090: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x1000fffd". Could someone explain what the error means and what I could do to fix it? Thank you.

```
            .data
matrixA:    .word 1,2,3,4,5,6   #Content of matrixA in array form
matrixB:    .word 5,6,7,8,9,10  #Content of matrixB in array form
sizeA:      .word 3,2       #Defines matrixA as being a 3x2 matrix
sizeB:      .word 2,3       #Defines matrixB as being a 2x3 matrix
result:     .word 0:9       #Initialize result as being an array of length 9 populated with 0
tab:        .asciiz "\t"
newLine:    .asciiz "\n"
            .globl _main

            .text
_main:  la $s0, matrixA     #s0 set to base address of matrixA
        la $s1, matrixB     #s1 set to base address of matrixB
        la $s2, sizeA       #s2 set to base address of sizeA
        nop
        lw $s3, 4($s2)      #s3 set to second val in sizeA (col #)
        nop
        lw $s2, 0($s2)      #s2 set to first val in sizeA (row #)
        la $s4, sizeB       #s4 set to base address of sizeB
        nop
        lw $s5, 4($s4)      #s5 set to second val in sizeB (col #)
        nop
        lw $s4, 0($s4)      #s4 set to first val in sizeB (row #)
        la $s6, result      #s6 set to base adress of result
        add $s7, $s5, $zero #s7 set to col # in result matrix
        add $t0, $zero, $zero   #Set t0 to zero. i = 0
        add $t1, $zero, $zero   #Set t1 to zero. j = 0
        add $t2, $zero, $zero   #Set t2 to zero. k = 0
        li $t3, 0       #Result position set to zero
i_loop: beq $t0, $s2, i_end #End i_loop if i = rowsA
        nop
j_loop: beq $t1, $s5, j_end #End j_loop if j = colsB
        nop
k_loop: beq $t2, $s4, k_end #End k_loop if k = rowsB
        nop

        #loop body

        li $t4, 0
        li $t5, 0
        li $t6, 0
                            #i * M + k - 1
        mul $t4, $t0, $s3   #i * #col in matrixA
        add $t4, $t4, $t2   #t4 + k
        addi $t4, $t4, -4      #t4 -1
        add $t4, $t4, $s0   #Now points to value at matrixA[i][k]
        lw $t4, 0($t4)      #Loads value at matrixA[i][k]

                    #k * M + j - 1
        mul $t5, $t2, $s5   #k * #col in matrixB
        add $t5, $t5, $t1   #t5 + j
        addi $t5, $t5, -4   #t5 -1
        add $t5, $t5, $s1   #t5 now points to value at matrixB[k][j]
        lw $t5, 0($t5)      #t5 loads value at matrixB[k][j]

                    #i * M + j - 1
        mul $t6, $t0, $s7   #i * #col in result
        add $t6, $t6, $t1   #t6 + j
        addi $t6, $t6, -4   #t6 -1
        add $t6, $t6, $s6   #t6 now points to value at result[i][j]
        lw $t8, 0($t6)      #t6 loads value at result[i][j]

        mul $t7, $t4, $t5   #t7 = matrixA[i][k]*matrixB[k][j]

        add $t9, $t8, $t7   #t8 = result[i][j] + matrixA[i][k]*matrixB[k][j]
        sw $t9, 0($t6)

        #end loop body

        addi $t2, $t2, 1    #k++
        j k_loop        #Return to start of k_loop
k_end:
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    #j++
        li $t2, 0       #Resets k counter to 0
        j j_loop        #Return to start of j_loop
j_end:
        addi $t0, $t0, 1    #i++
        li $t1, 0       #Resets j counter to 0
        j i_loop        #Return to start of i_loop

i_end:      #print
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three distinct problems, masked by the alignment fault.

You are computing array *indexes* [for an `int` array]. Before these can be added to the base address of the matrix, they must be converted into byte *offsets*.

Otherwise, you'll get [as you *did* get] an alignment fault because mips requires that addresses for words (i.e. `lw/sw`) are four byte aligned.

The second problem is when you try to subtract one from index. You're using a value of `-4` even though the comment says `-1`. So, on some level, you're mixing and matching index calculations and offset calculations

Consider a simple 1D `int` array/vector that starts at address `0x10010000`. The index to address mapping would be:

```
index   offset  address
-----   ------  --------
  0       0     10010000
  1       4     10010004
  2       8     10010008
```

In your code, you have:

```
    addi    $t4,$t4,-4              # t4 - 1
    add     $t4,$t4,$s0             # Now points to value at matrixA[i][k]
    lw      $t4,0($t4)              # Loads value at matrixA[i][k]
```

The final index (e.g. `$t4`) needs to be multiplied by `sizeof(int)` [which is 4] *before* adding in the matrix base address. The idiomatic way to do this is a left shift by 2.

Also, when adding addresses to addresses or offsets to addresses, you should use the *unsigned* version of `add` (i.e. `addu`) to guard against overflow/wrap which *can* occur for addresses.

```
    addi    $t4,$t4,-1              # t4 - 1
    sll     $t4,$t4,2               # convert index to byte offset
    addu    $t4,$t4,$s0             # Now points to value at matrixA[i][k]
    lw      $t4,0($t4)              # Loads value at matrixA[i][k]
```

You'll need to add this extra step whenever/wherever you do these index calculations.

The third problem is the final address `0x1000fffd` while not four byte aligned, is also *below* the lowest address allowed for the `.data` segment in `mars` (i.e `0x10010000`), so if you hadn't got the alignment fault, you'd be accessing non-existent memory [which will issue a different type of fault]

So, you may want to double check your index calculations for correctness to prevent the equivalent of accessing `int myarray[2]; myarray[-1] = 3;` [which is UB]